# Prove that there exists some $\epsilon$ > 0 and a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ such that $|a_{n_k} − 5| > \epsilon$ for all k.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

Question: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence which does not converge to 5. Prove that there exists some $\epsilon$ > 0 and a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ such that $|a_{n_k} − 5| > \epsilon$ for all k.

My Proof:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence which does not converge to 5 and $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number. By definition of a limit, $|a_n - 5| > \epsilon$. By Theorem, the subsequence ($a_{n_k}$) converges to the same value, p, as the original sequence ($a_n$), where p $\neq$ 5. Therefore, $|a_{n_k} - p | < \epsilon $. By definition of a limit, if g is any value that $(a_{n_k})$ is not convergent to, then $|a_{n_k} - g| > \epsilon$. Let g = 5. Therefore, $|a_{n_k} - 5| > \epsilon$.

Does this seem right? What can I do to improve it?

Comment: The definition of a limit is that if $(a_n)$ converges to $L$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that for any $n\geq N$, $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$. The limit not existing does not mean that $|a_n-5|>\varepsilon$ for any $n$. and we would never say that a sequence (or subsequence) coverges to a value $n$, since that is its index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct. You invoke the theorem that every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same value, but this is meaningless since the original sequence doesn't converge.

Rather, proceed as follows:

By (the negation of) the definition of limit, we have
$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall m: \exists n \geq m: |a_n -5| > \epsilon. \quad (*)$$

Choose a particular $\epsilon >0$ such that $(*)$ holds. Choose $n_1 \geq 1$ with $|a_{n_1}- 5| > \epsilon$.
Next, choose $n_2 \geq n_1 + 1$ with $|a_{n_2}-5| > \epsilon$ and continue playing this game (formally, you need an induction). In this way, you obtain a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_k$ with the required properties.

Comment: How do I figure out what the choose $\epsilon$ to be?

Comment: @red You don't get to choose $\epsilon$, it's given to you via the definition of "$a_n$ does not tend to $5$", which is labelled ($*$) above... (Any $\epsilon>0$ satisfying ($*$) is fine; that's why he said "choose $\epsilon>0$ so that ($*$) holds".)

Comment: @red I agree with what David C. Ullrich has said. The existence of such an epsilon is garantueed by the definition of negation of limit.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich ok i think i got it. i think the word "particular" made me think you need to choose an $\epsilon$